How to avoid HERE Maps API routing through underpasses when generating intermediate steps?
I'm using the HERE Maps API to generate a route between an origin and a destination, including several intermediate steps along the way. However, I've encountered an issue where some of the generated steps fall near underpasses, and HERE Maps often selects the lower road (underpass) instead of the upper road, which throws off the intended route.
Is there a way to influence the routing to prefer the upper road or avoid underpasses altogether? Perhaps a parameter related to elevation or road hierarchy that I can use to guide the API? Any suggestions or workarounds would be greatly appreciated!
This map shows a route generated using the HERE Maps API. The route is supposed to follow the highway (A16 Napoli-Canosa), but as shown in the map, the steps generated by the API appear to be routed incorrectly. Instead of sticking to the main highway, the route takes an unintended detour through the local roads and complex junctions nearby:

In this zoomed-in map view, the issue is more evident. The intended route should stay on the main highway (A16 Napoli-Canosa), but the HERE Maps API instead routes the path to the road beneath the highway. This discrepancy likely occurs due to the API prioritizing the underpass over the elevated highway route, which is not desired for this application:

When I make the API request, I provide the origin, the destination, and some intermediate steps. As mentioned, the route should follow these inputs accurately, but I'm encountering issues where the HERE Maps API sometimes routes the path through an underpass instead of sticking to the elevated highway.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

you cannot directly specify to avoid underpasses in the API request. However, you can influence the route by strategically placing waypoints or using the avoid[features] parameter to avoid certain features that might indirectly help in avoiding underpasses, such as tunnels if underpasses are classified as such in the API.
